# How to know when an operation has finished - Callback?

Tags: javascript, callback

I'd like to know when an operation has finished - It's an iteration where we don't know the size of the list be iterated over (it could be any length.)

Here's my code:

```
var array = [];

stripe.charges.list().autoPagingEach(function(charge) {

  var post  = {
    chargeId: charge.id,
    customerId: charge.customer,
    sourceId:charge.source.id,
    amount:(charge.amount/100).toFixed(2),
    description:charge.description,
    dateAndTime:moment(charge.created*1000).format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss'),
    chargeStatus:charge.status,
    failureMessage:charge.failure_message
  };

  array.push(post)

});
```

How can I `console.log(array.length)` once the iteration has finished?

I have seen some examples that use a callback with `Done()` which would appear to be what I'm after - But I can't figure how to factor it into this code.

Comment: The stripe documentation should state how to do this.

Comment: I agree! However a) it doesn't and b) I'm interested in the general case, something other than Stripe - an API where we retrieve a list of unknown length.

Comment: In the general case, you cannot know which callback will be the last. Something will need to tell you a) the number or b) when it's done

Comment: Interesting, yes - Where I had seen this before it was a predefined function....

Answer (score 0):

As per Stripe's documentation, [`stripe.charges.list()`](https://stripe.com/docs/api/charges/list?lang=node) returns an object with the list of charges in the `data` property.

You can do:

```
let charges = stripe.charges.list();
let pending_charges = charges.data.length;

charges.autoPagingEach(function(charge) {
    // do your thing

    pending_charges -= 1;
    if ( pending_charges == 0 ) {
        // call a function after the last charge has been processed
        // and be careful with failing autoPagingEach() executions
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks - However If I run your code above I get: `TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined`

Comment: (Also charges.data.length; always = 10 - hence the need to paginate.)

Comment: `charges. has_more` is a boolean that will tell you if there is more data or not.